# vim - accessing last several commands

Tags: vim

this is a bit dumb question but I can't seem to google it as I can't understand what to google.

I once saw this list of recent commands in vim, but can't undestand the command that called it:

[image]

googling reveals some other useful commands but not this one.
so - what is the hotkey for it?

Comment: This is the command-line window, where the command line can be edited just like editing text in any window. See [`:help cmdline-window`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-window), [`:help q:`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#q:) and [`:help E119`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#E199) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show the **history of commands** issued in **command mode** you have two options:

*First option:*

- press <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>

*Second option:*

- Check the cedit option : `:set cedit?` normally it holds the value **`^F`** (ctrl+f)
- Press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter the command mode and then press:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (if `cedit` holds another combination you need otherwise to use that instead)

> There are two ways to open the command-line window:
>
> **1.** **From Command-line mode, use the key specified with the 'cedit' option.    The default is CTRL-F when 'compatible' is not set.**
>
> **2.** **From Normal mode, use the** "**q:**", "q/" or "q?" command.    **This starts editing an Ex command-line** ("**q:**") or search string ("q/" or "q?").  Note that this is not possible while recording is in progress
> (the     "q" stops recording then).
>
> **When the window opens it is filled with the command-line history**.  The
> last line contains the command as typed so far.  The left column will
> show a  character that indicates the type of command-line being edited

This window is useful if you want to edit your previous commands especially if they are long and can save your time

You can close this window by pressing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Note that in the picture, you have provided, it is a window of last commands if it was a window of last search you will get the begining of lines starting by either **/** or **?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this you are asking for or not, but The command `:his` lists the command history. However, in many situations, a better solution is the **command-line window** which you can open by <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>. 
The advantage of the **command-line window** is that you can use all Vim's editing power, including searching with '/' in normal mode, or using whole-line completion  in insert mode.

Comment: This is much more a comment than an answer !